# Shell script to execute nohup against an inputed filename

Tags: bash, shell

I am constantly running commands like

```
nohup psql -d db -f foo1.sql >& foo1.out &
nohup psql -d db -f foo2.sql >& foo2.out &
```

I was wondering how to create a shellscript that takes as input the filename parameter like foo1.sql and runs the command above.

How do I write a script called test so that the command `./test foo1.sql` will execute the command

```
nohup psql -d db -f foo1.sql >& foo1.out &
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

outputFile="$(echo $1 | cut -d\. -f 1).out"

nohup psql -d db -f "$1" >& "$outputFile" &
```

It's not called with `./test(foo1.sql)` but `./test foo1.sql`, as shown after the question was edited.

Comment: If you don't pass the extension, you can simplify even further:
"""nohup psql -d db -f $1.sql >& $1.out &"""

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for calling the scripts would be:

```
./stest foo1.sql
```

there is a shell built-in called `test`, so don't call your script that.  No parentheses required when passing parameters.

The script is very simple:

```
if (( $# < 1 ))
then
    echo "Insufficient arguments" >&2
    exit 1
fi

name=${1%%\.*}
nohup psql -d db -f "$1" >& "$name.out" &
```