# Shell script to nohup every file in a directory

Tags: bash, shell

This is a follow up to the questions posted here [Shell script to execute nohup against an inputed filename](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14202947/1516064).

I am just trying to find away to modify the no_hup script below to execute against a whole directory of SQL scripts as opposed to just a single file.  So I am trying to find a good way to modify the below script to excute against a whole directory of files:

> How do I write a shell script so that I can run against a directory called test that contains the files foo1.sql, foo2.sql, foo3.sql
>
> ./nohup_sh test
>
> which will produce the ouput
>
> nohup psql -d db -f test/foo1.sql >& test/foo1.out &
>
> nohup psql -d db -f test/foo2.sql >& test/foo2.out &
>
> nohup psql -d db -f test/foo3.sql >& test/foo3.out &

This is the code I have been using from the previous answer called nohup_sh

```
#!/bin/bash

outputFile="$(echo $1 | cut -d\. -f 1).out"

nohup psql -d db -f "$1" >& "$outputFile" &
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file; do
    nohup psql -d db -f "$file" >& "${file%.*}.out" &
done
```

`${file%.*}` is [bash parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to perform the same as your `cut`
 command but with `bash builtin`

`for file` is a shorthand for `for file in "$@"`

Usage :

```
./script.bash sql_dir/*.sql
```

or

```
./script.bash *.sql
```

Comment: `${file%.*}` is **not** the same as `cut -d. -f 1`. Is is the same as `awk -v FS=. -v OFS=. 'NF--'` (that is drop only the final field). The equivalent parameter expansion to that cut command is `${file%%.*}`

Answer (score 1):

The following scripts searches for any `*.sql` files in the directory passsed as argument and executes the desired nohup command. Found file names are separated by null bytes to avoid problems with spaces or wildcards in file names.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
    find "$1/" -type f -name "*.sql" -print0 | while read -rd $'\0' file; do
        nohup psql -d db -f "$file" >& "${file%.*}.out" &
    done
else
    echo "$1 is no directory"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Call it like `script.sh somedir`.

Comment: `for file in $(find $1/ -name "*.sql")` is a bug : the script don't handle files with spaces in filenames